# How to compare only date part when delivery date is today

Tags: sql-server, getdate

I'm trying to create a report that gets records from a SQL Server database where the delivery date is today.

I've tried

```
select * from (tablename)
where delivery_date = getdate()
```

Although that didn't give me any errors, it didn't give me any records either.

I'm assuming it is because all dates are like:

```
2016-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

Perhaps, I need to truncate the date to remove the time-stamp and then try?

Comment: You may cast `getdate()` to `date` - this will cut off time. Or use date range if `delivery_date` stored may contain time too (if it is so I'd suggest to use this approach instead of casting both sides to `date`).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can try a query like below

```
select * from (tablename)
where CAST(delivery_date as date) = CAST(getdate() as date)
```

Also if all delivery dates have time part like `00:00:00.000` for sure then

```
select * from (tablename)
where delivery_date = CAST(getdate() as date)
```

would work as good.

Comment: If all delivery dates have no time portion, then also consider changing the column type to DATE to save some space.

Comment: works perfectly i have a time portion in database date and when i comparing dates i cant get results i want , thanks

Comment: Just SQL Server 2008 or later has DATE type.

Answer (score 5):

If delivery_date is always midnight (`00:00:00.000`), then compare it like this:

```
select * from (tablename)
where delivery_date = datediff(d, 0, getdate())
```

Using `datediff` like this is a quick way to truncate the time part of a datetime value.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just create 2 params.  One for `StartTime` and one for `EndTime` and use those in my query.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME,
        @EndTime DATETIME 

SET @StartTime = DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())
SET @EndTime = DATEADD(d,1,@StartTime)

SELECT  *
FROM    [tablename]
WHERE   delivery_date >= @StartTime
        AND delivery_date < @EndTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SET @Today= CONVERT(date, getdate())

select * from (tablename)
where delivery_date = @Today
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to remove the time part of the delivery_date field AND the GETDATE() value.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (tablename)
WHERE DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, delivery_date), 0) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```