# SQL IF statement for todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I'm trying to create a condition for my SQL, that shows a 1 if that row reflects today's day.

```
case when A.EntryDate = GETDATE() then '1' else '0' end as Today
```

That's accepted but it doesn't show anything but zeros. I've only worked with Access SQL and this one seems to dislike `Date()`

I've been looking all around for answers and I cannot seem to find one.

Comment: Is `EntryDate` a date or datetime?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare only date part when delivery date is today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018833/how-to-compare-only-date-part-when-delivery-date-is-today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetDate() method return datetime. To compare today's date you need to convert datetime to date.

```
case when cast(A.EntryDate as date)  = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that DATE was a type added in 2008.

For older versions:
     case when CAST(FLOOR(cast(A.EntryDate as FLOAT) AS DATETIME)  = CAST(FLOOR(cast(getdate() as FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) then 1 else 0 end